# AWS ALB returns 4XX although Target group returns 2xx

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

in my implementation I have a private ALB in the front and a target group in the back that points to ECS tasks. What I observed recently is that the ALB's returning quite a few 4XX responses whereas the target group in the back is not returning that many 4xx responses.

Can anyone advise please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reasons an ALB will return 4XX errors are [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html).

Some very common reasons an ALB will return a 4XX error when the backend did not are:

- `408` Request timeouts due to long-running backend queries and a low timeout setting on the load balancer.
- `403` Forbidden due to a WAF attached to the load balancer blocking a request.